# What happened to the Developer Story resume?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

Developer story resumes in PDF format used to look pretty cool.

What happened to the PDF version? Has that feature been removed?

Comment: you can see the Traditional view in Developer story and also download it as PDF

Comment: When you go to your Developer Story, do you not see the Save as PDF on the right side?

Comment: @Jigarb1992 I am not asking about the traditional view, asking about the story view.

Comment: opps! sorry @PritamBanerjee. Good Question :) I also need PDF in story view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A workaround, but I found the pdf here:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/apply/preview-pdf